# Can I install 'HoundHeater' against plastic FRP Wall Board?

Tags: safety, heaters

I have a question that is pet adjacent and I figured some of you on here might have one of these for your pet and know the answer.

I just purchased an Akoma Hound Heater Deluxe from amazon. I'm building my dog and insulated dog house to install it in. That way, I can let her out in the mornings and she'll have a warm dog house all day, no matter the outside temp.

I'm not set in stone about how I want to finish the inside, but right now, I'm highly leaning toward the following material to finish it: [.090 FRP Wall Panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-ft-x-8-ft-White-090-FRP-Wall-Board-MFTF12IXA480009600/100389836)

This material is sold by my local big box and is .090 thick plastic material. It resists anything clinging to it and would be easy to clean on a regular basis. My question is whether or not its safe to install the hound heater directly against this surface. If I finish the interior with wood, I wouldn't question, but while this product is not supposed to get hot on the exterior, I've read where people say they've had problems with the top of the exterior cage around the heater getting too hot. That's the front, though. I've never heard anyone comment on the back of the heater.

If anyone knows an answer to this question, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.